# Rails: How to display images in rows rather than one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, view

Currently my code results in a view that looks like this:

```
Lessons Start Now!
x
x
x
x
x
x
```

(where x = image)

I was wondering how I can make it display like this:

```
Lessons Start Now!
x   x   x
x   x   x
```

Here is my code for the index.html.erb

```
<h1>Lessons Start Now!</h1>
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <%= image_tag(lesson.image, :size => "100x50") %><br />
    <%= lesson.subject %><br />
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Lesson', new_lesson_path %>
```

The only thing I can think of is writing a for loop that has a count. It will insert the first images into one div class then once the count = 3, it would insert the next 3 into a different div. Maybe something special can be done using ul and li, or perhaps there is a rails way, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use CSS to do what you desire, let's say this is your template:

```
<h1>Lessons Start Now!</h1>
<% unless @lessons.empty? %>
<ul class="lessons">
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
    <li>
    <%= image_tag(lesson.image, :size => "100x50", :class => "thumbnail") %>
    <p class="subect"><%= lesson.subject %></p>
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'New Lesson', new_lesson_path %>
```

And this would be your CSS then:

```
.lessons {
  /* this is needed for the parent 
     to have height. read more 
     http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/
  */
  overflow:hidden;
  /* adjust width of this element
     if its width is not limited by its parent
  width: 300px;
  */
}
    .lessons li {
        /* add margins and paddings as you wish */
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do a table (or floating divs)

```
<table>
  <% @lessons.each_slice(3) do |lessons| %>
    <tr>
      <% lessons.each do |lesson| %>
        <td>
          <%= image_tag(lesson.image, :size => "100x50") %><br />
          <%= lesson.subject %>
        </td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: While tables allow to achieve the desired result, it's not a good idea to promote their use – tables for layout are not practical and goes against the idea of separating content (HTML) from styling (CSS).

Comment: @gryzzly, the answer is about general approach not about layouting. You can do whatever you want using `each slice` method

Comment: He did say "or floating divs". The basic approach is structurally correct.

Comment: the questions states “how would I make it display like this?”. visual formatting is done with CSS these days. Table without headings isn't structurally correct in my opinion.

Comment: Tables should not be used for layout. Use CSS

Comment: while being @grayzzly's answer is more accurate, i think @fl00r's answer is also can consider as it shows the concept of the loop

Comment: Good to learn the each_slice method, didn't know that existed! I guess both methods work and @gryzzly posted a 'floating div' method below. Although tables are an 'easy way' to solve this, it seems like leaving visual formatting to CSS is the best way to go. I will try out both methods, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

If it was me. I would move this to a helper and use the content_for helper and css to construct the layout you require. There are ways of doing what you want without this yet it is not good practise. Sorry, this is not a solution but it is a guide of what should be done in this sort of case. All the best. Let us know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a div with a width eg:

```
div.content
{
width: 305px;
}
```

In that div you place the images. The number of images shown per row will depend on the width of the div and the width of the images.

This approach has the advantage that it is purely done in design and not code.